# Phaser item is placed in array 18 times

Tags: arrays, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I'm working on an inventory system that puts items in an array with 18 slots. This is the code that places items in the array based on whether they are in a global array, using the has method I wrote, and whether or not the quest the item is involved with is complete.

```
if (this.has("key") && tutorial != "complete"){
        this.count = 0;
        while (this.count < 18){
            if (this.pack[this.count] == null){
                this.pack[this.count] = "key";
                break;
            }
            else {
                this.count += 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Other code then handles making the item visible in the inventory screen, and getting rid of the item once the quest is complete. For some reason, this code is placing the item, in this case a key, in all of the array's, wish is called pack, slots. (Slots is just what I like to call the spaces in an array)

I presume that the break statement is only breaking out of the if statement, and not the while loop as well. I did try replacing the break statement with this.count = 18; but that only got me the same results. Anyone out there know a better solution?

If it helps, I'm using Phaser 3 in VSCode employing arcade physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if this code is in the `update` function, the reason why this happens is that each time the update function is called a key is placed. the Best solution is to check if the key is in the array befor placing it.

With some builtin array functions like `indexOf`, `includes` or so.*([link to the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf))*

**Something like this:**

```
if ( his.has("key") && tutorial != "complete" && this.pack.indexOf("key") == -1){
    this.count = 0;
    while (this.count < 18){
        if (this.pack[this.count] == null){
            this.pack[this.count] = "key";
            break;
        }
        else {
            this.count += 1;
        }
    }
}
```